# Projection vector $y$ on $x$ , vector projection $y$ on $x$ and $y$ on normal $x$

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to know if my problem is correct. It is a homework from my university course.

The questions are:

> a) Find the projection of $y$ on $x$ 
>   b) Find the vector projection of $y$ on $x$ 
>   c) Find the vector projection of $y$ on the normal of $x$ 
>   where $x = [5,2,-1]$, $y = [0,1,1]$

#### a)

$P = \frac{[0,1,1] \cdot [5,2,-1]}{\sqrt{30}} = √30 / 30 *(-5) = -3√30 / 18$

#### b)

$yx = -3√30 / 18 * √30 / 30 [5,2,-1] = -3 / 18 [5,2,-1] = [-15/18,-6/18,3/18]$

#### c)

$y \perp x = [0,1,1] - [-15/18,-6/18,3/18] = [15/18,4/3,15/18]$

Comment: For starters, $x\cdot y = 5*0 + 2*1 + (-1)*1 \neq -5$.

Comment: What is the difference between questions a) and b)?

Comment: Just to way to rewrite it

Comment: (a) asks for Scalar projection? Scalar product is "1" not "-5". Corrected coordinates for (b) are (5/30,2/30,-1/30)

Answer (score 1):

Well, $y$ should be composed as $y=y_1+y_2$ where $y_1||x$ and $y_2\perp x$. By scalar multiplication by $x$ we get
$$x\cdot y = x\cdot y_1 + 0 $$
and $y_1=\alpha\cdot x$ for some $\alpha$ (because it is parallel to $x$). So, $x\cdot y=x\cdot\alpha x \implies \alpha=\displaystyle\frac{x\cdot y}{x\cdot x}$, then you get $y_1$ which answers a). For this, you will indeed need
$$x\cdot y = 5* 0 + 2*1 + (-1)*1 = 1 \ \text{ and }\ 
x\cdot x = 30. $$

For c), I assume the *normal* of $x$ is meant the *plane* of all vectors that are orthogonal to $x$. If you draw it, you will see that $y_2\ \ (=y-y_1)$ of the same decomposition gives the answer.